# How to set auto commit on table -SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a stored procedure where I need to commit only ERROR_LOG table, if any error or if we are terminating the procedure in between any process. And in this scenario all other changes has to be rolled back except ERROR_LOG table insertion.

How to Implement it?

Comment: You can use table variable, and then insert into ERROR_LOG from that variable

Answer (score 1):

Since table variables don't participate in transactions, you can use this fact to achieve your goal:

```
DECLARE @ErrorLog TABLE ( ID INT )

BEGIN TRANSACTION

INSERT  INTO @ErrorLog
        ( ID )
VALUES  ( 1 ),
        ( 2 )

ROLLBACK TRANSACTION

SELECT  *
FROM    @ErrorLog
```

Output:

```
ID
1
2
```

So, in your stored procedure instead of inserting in actual table insert into table variable and on error insert into actual table:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spTest
AS

BEGIN TRY
   DECLARE @ErrorLog TABLE(...)

   BEGIN TRANSACTION

   INSERT INTO @ErrorLog VALUES(...)

   COMMIT TRANSACTION      
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH

   ROLLBACK TRANSACTION

   INSERT INTO ErrorLog SELECT * FROM @ErrorLog

END CATCH
```

Comment: Just to add on, unless `AUTO COMMIT` is set to off, one doesn't need to explicitly `COMMIT`